# Improper integral

Tags: integration

I'd like some help to evaluate this integral :

$$I=\int^\infty_0 \frac{x-1}{\ln(x)}\,e^{-x} \,dx$$

I tried to use parameter then I've got an integral of gamma function which I don't know how to integrate it .

Any help will be greatly appreciate .

Comment: Have you tried integrating by parts?

Comment: "Solve" is the wrong word.  One may _evaluate_ an expression; one does not _solve_ an expression.  One can _solve_ an equation or _solve_ a problem.

Comment: Surly:yes,I have. @Michael Hardy  :  English is not my mother language, so some times I can't choose the right words. I'm very sorry and thanks for the alert.

Comment: @Lina: I very frequently see people using the word "solve" in this context.  It seems to be one of those words that students use whenever they don't know which word to use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First let $x = \mathrm{e}^t$, changing variables $\mathrm{d} x = \mathrm{e}^t \mathrm{d} t$

$$
   I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp( t - \mathrm{e}^t ) \frac{\mathrm{e}^t - 1}{t}  \mathrm{d} t
$$
In order to evaluate the integral, first evaluate

$$
  \mathcal{I}_s = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp( t - \mathrm{e}^t ) \mathrm{e}^{s t} \mathrm{d} t
   = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp( (s+1)t - \mathrm{e}^t ) \mathrm{d} t
$$
Changing variables back to $x$:
$$
  \mathcal{I}_s = \int_0^\infty x^{s} \mathrm{e}^{-x} \mathrm{d} x = \Gamma(s+1)
$$
Now use $\int_0^1 \mathrm{e}^{s t} \mathrm{d} s = \frac{\mathrm{e}^t - 1}{t}$ to get
$$
   I = \int_0^1 \mathcal{I}_s \, \mathrm{d}s = \int_0^1 \Gamma(1+s) \, \mathrm{d} s
$$
The integral $I$, thus, hardly has a closed form. Its approximate numerical [value](http://oeis.org/search?q=0.9227459506806306051&language=english&go=Search):
$$
I = 0.9227459506806306051438805
$$

---

**Added**: Rereading the answer, we can forgo changes of variables, observing $\int_0^1 x^s \mathrm{d} s = \frac{x-1}{\log x}$. Then

$$
   I = \int_0^\infty \frac{x-1}{\log x} \mathrm{e}^{-x} \mathrm{d} x = \int_0^\infty \int_0^1 x^s \mathrm{e}^{-x} \mathrm{d} s \mathrm{d} x  = \int_0^1 \int_0^\infty  x^s \mathrm{e}^{-x}  \mathrm{d} x \mathrm{d} s = \int_0^1 \Gamma(1+s) \mathrm{d} s
$$